# Python: Sorting functions in string by importance

Tags: python, function, lexer

I'm currently writing my own interpreted programming language without using any special librarys.
At the moment I try to work with functions. My goal is to have the ability to put **one function in another**:

```
output(sum(3,6), getsomething())
```

My lexer cuts it into pieces:

```
['output', '(', 'sum', '(', '3', ',', '6', ')', ',', 'getsomething', '(', ')', ')']
```

Now I would like to sort them that way:

1. sum (With arguments 3 & 6)
2. getsomething (With no arguments)
3. output (with return of sum and getsomething)

so my interpreter can run them in the right order.

**I really have no idea where to start, thanks for any help.**

Comment: I think you should convert it to some prefix/postfix notation. Please take a look on a deeper explanation of it: https://runestone.academy/runestone/books/published/pythonds/BasicDS/InfixPrefixandPostfixExpressions.html https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation

Comment: In my opinion the solution must depend on what you have so far. Because you need some sort of a "parenthesis" parser that match to the end. My recommendation would be to use a existing library, because in most cases this libraries are well tested.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this is what you want but an idea I had is the following:

Create a stack and start pushing the elements of the list (from the begining) into it. When you push a ")", pop everything until the first "(" and do one more pop (to know what function to execute). Notice that you popped a function and its variables which are independent from the rest of the line.

You can execute the function, push the value it returned to the stack and continue pushing the remaining elements of the list and doing the same for them.